# Need to permanently start IE9 inprivate mode on win7 64biz

Tags: windows, vba, windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I already found out that the following registry key will (normally) permanently start IE9 inprivate mode

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Safety\PrivacIE]
"FilteringMode"=hex(b):01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

(I even did not had Safety Key in my registry before and added it manually)

Unfortunately this seems not to work on windows7 64bit

Adding a shortcut with -inprivate is not an option for me as I wanna use IE9 via VBA

Any tips / advice?

Comment: Can you shell IE9 with the switch and GetObject?

Comment: don't know how to do it:

Comment: @Remou don't know how to do it.
tried: 

        ' Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        ' Set obj = objShell.Exec("%ProgramFiles%/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe -private")

but i need the InternetExplorer API so I need to somehow cast Object to InternetExplorer in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Cobbled together from all over the place:

```
Dim sh As Object, oWin As Object, IE As Object
Dim wss As Object

Set wss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

wss.exec "%ProgramFiles%/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe -private"     
''You will probably need a delay here
For Each oWin In sh.Windows
    If TypeName(oWin.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        Set IE = oWin
        Exit For
    End If
Next

With IE
    .navigate "http://stackoverflow.com"

    Do While .busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While .readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: I modfied the for next loop to:
For Each oWin In sh.Windows
        Debug.Print TypeName(oWin.Document)
        If TypeName(oWin.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            Set IExp = oWin
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

and got:

IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3
IShellFolderViewDual3

in Direct Window

therefore I assume that I cannot grab the Iexplorer Window? Any helP

Comment: Did you delay at the comment line? Try stepping through the code to give internet explorer a chance to load. If that works, you can consider using two procedures or a delay.

Comment: you need to check on the o.Win.Title = "Windows Internet Explorer" otherwise it won't find the windows (as given above TypeName() will not work as shown above, at least on my system and you need to add a sleep after the ie fires up (Remou thanks for the tip!)